# Express: Styles/Scripts called by Template Engine (Pug) not Loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm currently trying to load my scripts and styles called in Pug. However, even when I use express to serve static files, the only thing that loads is the webpage with no styles, images or scripts. This is my directory structure:

[image]

My server.js file executed by Gulp contains this:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.set('views', 'src/pages')
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../docs')))
console.log(path.join(__dirname, '../../docs'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Welcome!')
    res.render('index');
})

// Get post data from login and use encodeURIComponent on password with POST URL
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Request received')
    res.end()
})

let server = app.listen(8080)
console.log('Listening on port 8080')
```

Here's the error that gets returned:
[image]

I'm not exactly sure what it is I'm doing wrong. Could someone help me figure out what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References to static assets should not include the folder you set as static in express. For example:
    /docs/styles/main.css -> /styles/main.css

Also try doing
    app.use(express.static('docs'))
That should be enough.